# ICMP recvfrom function always receive data even though the destination was shutdown

Tags: ping, icmp

I wrote a program in C to ping a machine and receive the echo from that machine to detect if the machine is still alive. My code as following please:

```
#define PING_PKT_S 64
#define PORT_NO 0
#define PING_SLEEP_RATE 1000000
#define RECV_TIMEOUT 1

int pingloop=1;

struct ping_pkt {
    struct icmphdr hdr;
    char msg[PING_PKT_S-sizeof(struct icmphdr)];
};

unsigned short checksum(void *b, int len) {
    unsigned short *buf = b;
    unsigned int sum=0;
    unsigned short result;
    for ( sum = 0; len > 1; len -= 2 )
        sum += *buf++;
    if ( len == 1 )
        sum += *(unsigned char*)buf;
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    result = ~sum;
    return result;
}

//to check if this machine is actively working
int isActiveNow(){
    const char *pre = "161.";
    char *prefixArr[] = {pre};
    char myIp[64];
    memset(myIp, 0, sizeof(myIp));
    get_local_ip(myIp, prefixArr);
    printf("---isActiveNow:%s\n",myIp);
    if(myIp[0]=='\0'){
        printf("Not Active Now!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void intHandler(int dummy) {
    pingloop=0;
}

long current_timestamp() {
    struct timeval te;
    gettimeofday(&te, NULL);
    long milliseconds = te.tv_sec*1000LL + te.tv_usec/1000;
    return milliseconds;
}

void display(void *buf, int bytes){
    int i;
    struct iphdr *ip = buf;
    struct icmphdr *icmp = buf+ip->ihl*4;
    printf("---------------------Start Display\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < bytes; i++ ){
        printf("%c", ((unsigned char*)buf)[i]);
    }
    printf("---------------------End Display\n");
}

int failedNum = 0;

// make a ping request
void send_ping(int ping_sockfd, char *ping_ip) {
    int ttl_val=64, msg_count=0, i, addr_len, msg_received_count=0;

    struct ping_pkt pckt;
    struct sockaddr_in r_addr;
    struct timespec time_start, time_end;

    // set socket options at ip to TTL and value to 64,
    if (setsockopt(ping_sockfd, SOL_IP, IP_TTL,  &ttl_val, sizeof(ttl_val)) != 0) {
        printf("Setting socket options to TTL failed!\n");
        return;
    }else{
        printf("\nSocket set to TTL..\n");
    }

    // send icmp packet in an infinite loop
    while(pingloop) {
        sleep(2);
        if(isActiveNow()){
            printf("--current is active!");
            continue;
        }
        //filling packet
        bzero(&pckt, sizeof(pckt));

        pckt.hdr.type = ICMP_ECHO;
        pckt.hdr.un.echo.id = getpid();

        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
            pckt.msg[i] = 'w';
        }
        pckt.msg[i] = 0;
        pckt.hdr.un.echo.sequence = msg_count++;
        pckt.hdr.checksum = checksum(&pckt, sizeof(pckt));

        long s1 = current_timestamp();
        struct hostent *hostentObj;
        hostentObj = gethostbyname(ping_ip);
        struct sockaddr_in ping_addr;
        ping_addr.sin_port = 0;
        ping_addr.sin_family = hostentObj->h_addrtype;
        ping_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*) hostentObj->h_addr;

        //Using synchronize
        if ( sendto(ping_sockfd, &pckt, sizeof(pckt), 0,  (struct sockaddr*) &ping_addr, sizeof(ping_addr)) <= 0) {
            printf("\nPacket Sending Failed!\n");
        }

        struct timeval tv_out;
        tv_out.tv_sec = 10;
        tv_out.tv_usec = 0;
//        setsockopt(ping_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&tv_out, sizeof tv_out);

        struct sockaddr_in myAddr;
        unsigned char buf[1024];
        int len=sizeof(myAddr);

        bzero(buf, sizeof(buf));
        struct ping_pkt pckt2;
        int bytes = recvfrom(ping_sockfd, &pckt2, sizeof(pckt2), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&myAddr, &len);
        printf("---------------------bytes len:%d\n",bytes);
        if ( bytes > 0 ){
            display(&pckt2, bytes);
            long s2 = current_timestamp();
            printf("from %s msg_seq=%d ttl=%d rtt = %ld ms. pckt.hdr.type=%d \n", ping_ip, msg_count,ttl_val, (s2-s1), pckt.hdr.type);
        }else{
            printf("-------NO RESPONSE!!!!!!\n");
            failedNum++;
            //maximum detected failed number is 10
            if(failedNum>3){
                printf("--The other server dead!!!\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

bool prefix(const char *pre, const char *str){
  return strncmp(pre, str, strlen(pre)) == 0;
}

void get_local_ip(char *pubIp, char *prefixArr[]){
  char *ip;
  int fd, intrface, retn = 0;
  struct ifreq buf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
  struct ifconf ifc;

  if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) >= 0){
    ifc.ifc_len = sizeof(buf);
    ifc.ifc_buf = (caddr_t)buf;
    if (!ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFCONF, (char *)&ifc)){
      intrface = ifc.ifc_len/sizeof(struct ifreq);
      while (intrface-- > 0){
        if (!(ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, (char *)&buf[intrface]))){
          ip=(inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in*)(&buf[intrface].ifr_addr))->sin_addr));

          int len = 0,i = 0;
          len = sizeof(prefixArr) / sizeof(*prefixArr);
          for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              if(prefix(prefixArr[i],ip)){
                  strcpy(pubIp,ip);
                  return;
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    close(fd);
  }
}

// Driver Code
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sockfd;
    char *pingIp;

    char *prefixArr[] = { "11.","10.","172."};
    char myIp[64];
    memset(myIp, 0, sizeof(myIp));
    get_local_ip(myIp, prefixArr);
    //the other server's ip for detecting it's alive or dead
    pingIp = argv[1];
    printf("my ip:%s-----ping ip:%s\n", myIp, pingIp);

    //socket()
    sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    struct sockaddr_in r_addr;
    r_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    r_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(myIp);
    r_addr.sin_port = 0;

    bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &r_addr, sizeof(r_addr));

    if(sockfd<0){
        printf("\nSocket file descriptor not received!!\n");
        return 0;
    }else{
        printf("\nSocket file descriptor %d received\n", sockfd);
    }

    //once error seen, it will stop the loop
    signal(SIGINT, intHandler);//catching interrupt

    //send pings continuously
    send_ping(sockfd,  pingIp);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the value of myReceiveBytes is alway 64, even though the destination server has already been shutdown.

Comment: Can you compile the code above? How do you know, myReceiveBytes is always 64?

Comment: the code can be compile successfully, when I ran the code, I print out myReceiveBytes, it always print out 64.

Comment: I think you forgot to include some codes as I don't see main(). Besides that, you did not define msg_count++ nor ping_sockfd. Also, len suppose to be socklen_t. You also redefined r_addr twice.

Comment: hi Kevin, thank you so much! I posted the the whole code, it compiled and ran ok, just it's behavior not as I expected, as I mentioned the variable myReceiveBytes always return 64 even though the dest server was shutdown. From other perspective the response time become shorter and shorter, in the beginning of run the ping response time is 100ms(this is right), but after a few pings, the response time become 0 or 1ms.

Comment: What does the network look like?  Is there a chance there's another device on the network answering the ICMP for the server that is down, e.g. a misconfigured switch or server?

Comment: hi CXJ, I don't think so, no misconfigured switch or server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not actually decoding the received packet. In all likelihood, what you are receiving is an ICMP Destination Unreachable packet either [from your own host](https://superuser.com/questions/453933/pinging-a-machine-on-my-local-network-gets-an-unreachable-response-from-my-own) or from your gateway.

Something along these lines:

```
#include <netinet/ip.h> /* struct iphdr */
...
...
struct sockaddr_in peerAddr;
unsigned char buf[1024];
unsigned int len = sizeof(peerAddr);

int bytes_received = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0,
                              (struct sockaddr *) &peerAddr, &len);
if (bytes_received > 0) {
  printf("ICMP packet received from %s\n", inet_ntoa(peerAddr.sin_addr));
  struct icmphdr *icmp = (struct icmphdr *) (buf + sizeof(struct iphdr));
  switch (icmp->type) {
  case ICMP_ECHOREPLY:      printf("Type: ICMP_ECHOREPLY\n"); break;
  case ICMP_DEST_UNREACH:   printf("Type: ICMP_DEST_UNREACH\n"); break;
  case ICMP_SOURCE_QUENCH:  printf("Type: ICMP_SOURCE_QUENCH\n"); break;
  case ICMP_REDIRECT:       printf("Type: ICMP_REDIRECT\n"); break;
  case ICMP_ECHO:           printf("Type: ICMP_ECHO\n"); break;
  case ICMP_TIME_EXCEEDED:  printf("Type: ICMP_TIME_EXCEEDED\n"); break;
  case ICMP_PARAMETERPROB:  printf("Type: ICMP_PARAMETERPROB\n"); break;
  case ICMP_TIMESTAMP:      printf("Type: ICMP_TIMESTAMP\n"); break;
  case ICMP_TIMESTAMPREPLY: printf("Type: ICMP_TIMESTAMPREPLY\n"); break;
  case ICMP_INFO_REQUEST:   printf("Type: ICMP_INFO_REQUEST\n"); break;
  case ICMP_INFO_REPLY:     printf("Type: ICMP_INFO_REPLY\n"); break;
  case ICMP_ADDRESS:        printf("Type: ICMP_ADDRESS\n"); break;
  case ICMP_ADDRESSREPLY:   printf("Type: ICMP_ADDRESSREPLY\n"); break;
  default:                  printf("Type: <0x%02x>\n", icmp->type); break;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! so could you please give me a guid that how to modify my code to decode the receive packet correctly?

Comment: @Jack According to [the manpage for raw](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html), IPv4 packets received on a raw socket will have the IPv4 header followed by an ICMP Header. The ICMP header has Type and Code fields, and if you are looking for a "ping reply", you want the Type field in the ICMP header to be "Echo Reply", not "Destination Unreachable" or anything else.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works! Just one more question please, If the peer server is DEST_UNREACH, why the local server still could receive bytes from that peer server? were the bytes replied by peer switch or router?

Comment: @Jack Pay attention to the peer IP address printed by my sample code. It could be the address of a router that is telling you that it cannot find the host, and sometimes it can also be the IP address of your own computer (where you are running this program) - see the link I wrote in my answer.

Comment: thank you! Do you have idea why the ping response time faster and faster, the response time was 100ms in the beginning a few hundreds ping, but afterwards the response time become 5ms or 1ms. so weird.